# Pgsql- How to filter report days with pgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table **Transaction** which has data as following:

---

**Transaction**

```
| id         | user_id     | amount      | created_at   |
|:-----------|------------:|:-----------:| :-----------:|
|    1       |        1    |     100     |  2021-09-11  |  
|    2       |        1    |     1000    |  2021-09-12  |
|    3       |        1    |     -100    |  2021-09-12  |
|    4       |        2    |     200     |  2021-10-13  |
|    5       |        2    |     3000    |  2021-10-20  |
|    6       |        3    |     -200    |  2021-10-21  |
```

- I want to filter this data by this: **last 4days, 15days, 28days**:

**Note:** If user click on select option 4days this will filter last 4 days.

I want this data

1. total commission (sum of all transaction amount * 5%)
2. Total Top up
3. Total Debut: which amount (-)

Please help me out and sorry for basic question!

Expect result:

** If user filter last 4days:

Let's say current date is: 2021-09-16

So result:

```
- TotalCommission (1000 - 100) * 5
- TotalTopUp: 1000
- TotalDebut: -100
```

Comment: Hi there. Could you add the expected result based on this data sample and perhaps what you've tried so far?

Comment: @JimJones I have updated what I expected please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) * 0.05 AS TotalCmomission,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount > 0) AS TotalUp,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE amount < 0) AS TotalDown
FROM t
WHERE created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - 4 * INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

This assumes that there are no future `created_at` (which seems like a reasonable assumption).  You can replace the `4` with whatever value you want.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE - 4 * INTERVAL '1 DAY'` can be simplified to `CURRENT_DATE - 4`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I like being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the aggregate functions `sum`, `max` and `min`. Last four days should look like this:

```
SELECT 
  sum(amount)*.05 AS TotalComission,
  max(amount) AS TotalUp,
  min(amount) AS TotalDebut
FROM t
WHERE created_at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-4 AND CURRENT_DATE;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=425a34796aeb59e27109a3577b790bb4)

Answer (score 0):

Your description indicates specifying the number of days to process and from your expected results indicate you are looking for results by user_id (perhaps not as user 1 falls into the range). Perhaps the the best option would be to wrap the query into a SQL function. Then as all your data is well into the future you would need to parameterize that as well. So the result becomes:

```
create or replace 
function Commissions( user_id_in     integer default null
                    , days_before_in integer default 0
                    , end_date_in    date    default current_date
                    )
 returns table( user_id         integer
              , totalcommission numeric
              , totalup         numeric
              , totaldown       numeric
              ) 
 language sql
as $$
    select user_id 
         , sum(amount) * 0.05
         , sum(amount) filter (where amount > 0) 
         , sum(amount) filter (where amount < 0) 
      from transaction
     where (user_id = user_id_in or user_id_in is null) 
       and created_at <@ daterange( (end_date_in - days_before_in * interval '1 day')::date 
                                  , end_date_in
                                  , '[]'::text          -- indicates inclusive of both dates
                                  )
    group by user_id;
$$;
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a6096f1abdadcc1a8fd9f565993dbe2). You may just want to play around with the parameters and see the results.